# integrating third party application with Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm

I'm trying to integrate third party application with the dynamics CRM.

> Authenticate the Dynamics User > Importing all the users data into third party application is my target.
>
> But I'm unable to find the proper way to do this. I have gone through the developer docs but didn't find the solution. Can anyone please help me with this ?

Comment: There are an enormous number of ways you can do this from custom coding it to using an ETL tool like SSIS with KingswaySoft or Scribe Online.

If you are thinking of custom coding it, what language are you thinking about using?

Comment: Also, please review [ask].

Comment: Thank you.My plan is to use Dynamics CRM Web API. Currently, I am using Java language. Previously I did a OAUTH2 flow using Azure. I registered my application in Application Registration Portal https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/Disambiguation?ru=https%3A%2F%2Fapps.dev.microsoft.com%2F  and configured with the Azure also. Now, my question is how do i get the dynamics user data ?(Thing is I did oauth2 flow for azure)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the clarification. You can get the Web API URL from Settings > Customization > Developer Resources > Instance Web API.

It will be something like:
`https://myOrg.api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/`

Using that URL you can query the system and get JSON results.

Going to the root URL will give you the collection name (a.k.a. `EntitySetName`) of all the entities in the system (which for users is `systemusers`).

Generally the `EntitySetName` will be the plural of the entity (i.e. just add 's'), but there are some quirky rules for making plurals so its best to confirm the entity set name via the API or a tool like [XrmToolbox's](http://xrmtoolbox.com) Metadata Browser.

The most basic query for users would be:
`https://myOrg.api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/systemusers`

It will return all fields of all users.

To get a set of fields:
`https://myOrg.api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/systemusers?$select=salutation,fullname,jobtitle,createdon,internalemailaddress`

To add a couple filters:
`https://myOrg.api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/systemusers?$select=salutation,fullname,jobtitle,createdon,internalemailaddress&$filter=isdisabled%20eq%20false%20and%20address1_line1%20ne%20null`

Of course you have to do this with Java's XmlHttpRequest. When querying data you can use `HTTP GET`.

To test the above queries quickly you can simply login to the D365 web client then paste a query into the browser's address bar.

You may also want to check out Jason Lattimer's [CRMRESTBuilder](https://github.com/jlattimer/CRMRESTBuilder). While it doesn't build Java, it gives you a UI to create JavaScript XmlHttpRequests, which you can then translate to Java.

And here's some [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/webapi/web-api-query-data-sample) on querying the Web API.

Comment: Thank you :) I will try with this info.

Comment: Hi Aron,   registered my application in http://apps.dev.microsoft.com and established a OAUTH connection successfully , it is generating access_tokens. But when I use this token to get  the data from the dynamics organization I am getting 401 - unauthorized error. Can you please help me with this. (logged in  with my organization credentials only)

Comment: [This](https://medium.com/capgemini-dynamics-365-team/dynamics-365-v-9-webapi-authentication-examples-in-java-60a04e36dac9) might help...

Comment: I followed the above blog, I am getting resource parameter not found error. (I am using oAUTH2.0)